# Which is better? Between using image file and draw vector shape

Tags: wpf, silverlight, performance, windows-phone-7, vector

As I said on the title.
I just want to know which is better between using image files and drawing vector shapes (or path).
I know that using vector is better for appearance but what about performance.

And if this depends on cases. Can anyone explain.

(This question may include WP7, Silverlight, WPF or even in general cases.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a general answer to compare pros/cons of Bitmap (what I think you mean by "image file") vs. Vector.

Bitmap-based images (gif, tiff, jpeg, png, bmp) are essentially the concept of mapping colours (and other data such as alpha layer) to a pixel grid. Different file formats offer variations of what is supported and levels of compression but this is the high-level concept. The complete map of pixels and data is stored in the file as a matrix/table.

Vector-based images, as you say, are path based. Instead of storing information by pixels, the file format will store geometric points and data.

The pros for bitmaps are:

- They usually render faster than a vector. This is because there is minimal computation involved in presenting the image (just take the pixel map and display).
- They handle "photographic" content better than a vector.
- They are more portable than vector. GIF, JPEG, PNG, BMP are more standard than any vector format (where usually Adobe has the market)

The cons for bitmaps are:

- They don't scale without degradation (pixelization)
- Manipulation (i.e. resizing, blurring, lighting, etc) of a bitmap is more processor expensive than a vector
- The files are usually much larger than vector-based files

The pros for vectors are:

- Flexible for scaling and manipulation
- Smaller file formats than vector
- Ideal for print and animation (i.e. manipulating a shape to produce the animation effect)

The cons for vectors are:

- Render time, depending on the complexity of the vector, can be longer
- Portability most formats are highly proprietary
- Work for "graphic" based images but not useful for photorealism

Hope this helps.

Comment: WOW! What a detailed explanation. Thank you very much for your answer, this helps me a lot to understand vector and image.

Comment: Vector format is also awesome for Theming apps. you just change the color of the fill and it can be used for a dark or light theme. With bitmaps, you will need one image per theme usually, unless you want to use same images for all themes.

Answer (score 5):

Jeremiah Morrill gave a [great overview of WPF rendering](http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/) that basically shows a vector will always be more expensive to render than an image. Basically an image gets treated as a directx texture...no matter the size, scaling or whatever, there is a set constant cost for rendering an image. As Jer's overview shows, even the simplest vector image takes a number of operations to render in WPF. The moral of the story is that when giving an option, go for the image instead of vector.

Answer (score 2):

Based on our experience with Windows Phone 7 (Non-mango) apps, we find using Images instead of using drawing produces a far more responsiveness hence UX Performance for continuous animation in pages. (YMMV)

Answer (score 1):

I would initially say that images render faster than vectors. The complexer the vector, more time it takes to render. The bigger the image, more time to render.

I'm going to speculate that (in Silverlight terms) most of the current video hardware is capable of directly handling the images rendering getting so a boost in the performance. I'm not sure if calculations for vectors can be done at video hardware level.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of Windows Phone 7, you'll typically get faster rendering of images/bitmaps rather than paths/vectors. As a general rule for mobile development, due to the constrained resources on the device and the increased need to consider performance, if you can do something once, such as preparing an image, at design (or compile) time that definitely preferable to doing it multiple times on each client.

Be very careful of applying rules across platforms (WPF, Silverlight & WP7) as they are used for different things in different situations and are under different constraints. Things you have to consider on the phone may not be as much of an issue in a WPF app running on an high powered PC.